# Linked lists with strings

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to create a program that begins by parsing a number of strings and adding them into a Linked List, and then ending by printing out the occurrences of each string.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node
{
    char* word;
    int count;
    struct Node *next;
};

Node *head = NULL;
Node *curr = NULL;

Node* listAdd(char* word, bool toEnd) {
    Node* tmp = head;
    while (tmp) {
        if (strcmp(tmp, word) == 0) {
            tmp->count++;
            return tmp;
        }
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    printf("allocate memory for node");
    Node *ptr = malloc(sizeof(Node));

    printf("initialize count to 0");
    ptr->count = 0;

    printf("allocate memory to hold word");
    ptr->word = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);

    printf("copy the current word");
    strcpy(ptr->word, word);

    ptr->next = NULL;

    if (toEnd)
    {
        curr->next = ptr;
        curr = ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        ptr->next = head;
        head = ptr;
    }
    return ptr;
}

void printList()
{
    Node *ptr = head;
    while (ptr)
    {
        printf("\nThe word [%s] has had [%d] occurrences.\n",ptr->word, ptr->count);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

char* readWord()
{
    static char buffer[100];
    scanf("%s", buffer);
    printf("listAdd() call");
    listAdd(buffer);
    return buffer;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    printf("How many words would you like to type?\n");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    for (i; i != 0; i--)
    {
        readWord();
    }
    printList();
}
```

Current output:

```
How many words would you like to input?
3
hi
bye
yes
How many words would you like to input?
Occurrences: 12086064
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated — I'm still a novice at C coming from C# :(

Comment: Suggest you persevere and debug this yourself rather than turning to SO straight away. In particular, fire up your favourite debugger, step through your program and check at each stage whether the code is operating as you expect. Or even a few trusty debug print statement will go a long way in helping you understand what your program is actually doing.

Comment: You don't use function `searchList`. `count` is not initialised..

Comment: You also need to allocate space to hold the actual string in `listAdd()` e.g `ptr->word = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);` and then copy over the string `strcpy(ptr->word, word);`

Comment: @Cyclone Do I also need to allocate memory for the count too then?

I think the     searchList function was a pretty bad idea. I'm just going to increment the count in     listAdd() instead.

And I've tried debug print statements before posting here — none of them ever printed.

Comment: @Sleepless - Nope, but you need to allocate memory to store each word in your node (not just a pointer) or else they will all point to the last word entered since you they are getting overwritten each time `readWord()` is called.

Comment: @Cyclone Thanks for the hint in the right direction but I'm still getting the same outcome, so I'm either calling     strcpy at the wrong time or I still haven't allocated memory properly yet. Can you give me another shove please?

Comment: You `malloc` twice when you add a node. That's nonsesne, you need to allocate at most once, namely the memory for a new node. In the case where the word is already in the list, you don't need to allocate; you just need to increment the existing node's counter.

Comment: @Sleepless, there is useless malloc() towards the end of listAdd() function and this malloc address is being returned. If anyhow you are using the returned Node * ptr then you will definitely get wrong result.

Comment: Suspicious values like your result are very likely caused by not initialising data. And indeed: You allocate a node with `malloc`, which contains garbage at the beginning. Then you don't set the count to one, you increment the count. Incrementing an uninitialised garbage value still yields garbage.

Comment: Also note that in your updated code you allocate memory for `ptr->word`, copy the word to that memory and two lines later you lose that memory by overwriting `ptr->word` with `word` again. Throw out that last assignment.

Comment: @MOehm Should I simplify the two mallocs into one such as        `malloc(sizeof(Node) + strlen(word))` then?

Comment: @Sleepless: No. I referred to the two allocations to `ptr`. The second allocation overwrites the first and you will effectively lose what you have done before in the function. (I see that the last, superflous allocation really is the third one. Sorry for the ambiguity.) The allocation to `ptr->word` is required and should be uncoupled from the node allocation. But you do the same here: allocate to `ptr->word` and the overwrite it with something else later.

Comment: @Moehm Ah, got it. Unfortunately even after initializing `count` to 0 & removing the 3rd `ptr->word`, I'm still getting the same outcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code contains a couple of mistakes. First you are allocating your `Node` ptr twice:

```
Node* listAdd(char* word, bool toEnd) {
  // .. 

  Node *ptr = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  return ptr;
}
```

Remove the last one, right before the `return` statement.

You will also need to allocate memory to hold each read word. Right now you are overwriting the buffer each time you call `readWord()`. You would then do something like:

```
Node* listAdd(char* word, bool toEnd) {
  // allocate memory for node
  Node *ptr = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  // initialize count to 0
  ptr->count = 0;
  // allocate memory to hold word
  ptr->word = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
  // copy the current word
  strcpy(ptr->word, word);
```

Your `printList()` function need look something like this:

```
void printList() {
  Node* ptr = head;
  while(ptr) {
    printf("Word: %s %d\n", ptr->word, ptr->count);
    ptr = ptr->next;
  }
}
```

Since you never check if the entered word already exists in your list each word will always be reported as having 1 occurance. This could be fixed like this:

```
// check if the word alreay exists in the list and then increment its count by 1
// this code should go at the top (before allocating ptr) in listAdd()
Node* tmp = head;
while(tmp) {
   if(strcmp(tmp->word, word) == 0) {
     tmp->count++;
     return tmp;
   }
   tmp = tmp->next;
}
```

Of course you should also free the allocated memory before exiting your application:

```
void freeList() {
  Node* ptr = head;
  Node* tmp = 0;
  while(ptr) {
    tmp = ptr->next;
    free(ptr->word);
    free(ptr);
    ptr = tmp;
  }
```

Comment: I've updated OP to as you suggested but I'm still getting the same outcome. Is it because I'm not initializing `count`?

Comment: @Sleepless - Yes, that might be the problem. Look at the above code, I'm initializing count to 0.

Comment: Yeah I saw your edit and tried it on my machine first (and edited OP rather late!), yet still no luck. Also while we're on this note, should I initialize `count` to 0 in my `if (head == NULL)` block instead, and then proceed to increment it after the block?

Comment: @Sleepless - Changing the code as above works fine for me?

Comment: @Sleepless - Here you have a link with a working code http://codeshare.io/5VPUo Don't forget that you should deallocate the used memory e.g `free(ptr->word); free(ptr);` This should be done for all nodes in the list before exiting the program.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the assistance Cyclone — it's been a good learning experience!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use malloc and strcpy to store words, and strcmp to compare them.  What you're doing is saving repeated references to the buffer array that you're reading the words into.